# Module Position field is not clickable inside a repeatable field

Tags: templates, module-params

I tried to include [Module Position field](https://docs.joomla.org/ModulePosition_form_field_type) inside a [Repeatable field](https://docs.joomla.org/Repeatable_form_field_type). The module choices modal is showed up but the available module options are not clickable. Is it a joomla bug or I missed something here?

When I looked at the browser console I found this error message :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of nulljSelectPosition_jform_params_position @ index.php?option=com_templates&view=style&layout=edit&id=9:93onclick @ index.php?option=com_modules&view=positions&layout=modal&tmpl=component&function=jSelectPosition_jf…:108
```

Comment: Hmm, this does sound like a bug. I'd suggest posting it as an issue on the [Github Repo for Joomla](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms)

Comment: @Lodder done thanks http://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/7595

Comment: Update on this for J3.4.4 on Firefox. Selecting the position closes the modal as expected, however it does not populate the input field and no error is shown in the console log.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the repeatable field type is broken for any field that requires Javascript logic.

Here is the relevant issue in Joomla https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/6882